# Error loading angular javascript files after build and deploy on IIS

Tags: angular, iis

We have been working with angular for some years, from version 2 to version 9.
We have always deployed our app under IIS 8.5. No problem with this. It works.
In our app we have service workers in order to enable PWA.

If we delete all previous app file from our site root before copying there the new ones, we often have errors when opening site. The error is:

```html
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
polyfills-es2015.b8603dcd0659ba4c1e2e.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
main-es2015.b542f2fdb703ba496e2c.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

The result is a blank page. If we refresh the page, then, the most of the time it works (sometimes not, untill we close browser and force cache delete)

It seems that type of files js are not consedered the correct ones by IIS.

We have never tried to run app under another webserver, but I'm pretty sure it could be something related to IIS cache management.

This is our IIS config:

```html
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="Vary" />
        <add name="Vary" value="Accept-Encoding,User-Agent" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" name="gzip" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript" />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json" />
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>

<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />

<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="180.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="public" />
    
    <remove fileExtension=".html" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <remove fileExtension=".css" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />
    <remove fileExtension=".js" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
    <remove fileExtension=".png" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png" />
    <remove fileExtension=".jpg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
    <remove fileExtension=".rss" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <remove fileExtension=".xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <remove fileExtension=".mp3" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
    <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ogv" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
    <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <remove fileExtension=".svgz" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ttc" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttc" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
    <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    <remove fileExtension=".crx" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension" />
    <remove fileExtension=".xpi" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall" />
    <remove fileExtension=".safariextz" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".safariextz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <remove fileExtension=".flv" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv" />
    <remove fileExtension=".f4v" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ico" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
    <remove fileExtension=".webp" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
    <remove fileExtension=".htc" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component" />
    <remove fileExtension=".vcf" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
    <remove fileExtension=".torrent" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/x-bittorrent" />
    <remove fileExtension=".cur" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
    <remove fileExtension=".webapp" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webapp" mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8" />
</staticContent>

<rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>

<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="10000" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" maxUrlLength="2000" />
    <compilation debug="true" urlLinePragmas="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <sessionState timeout="120" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

    <location path="index.html">
        <system.webServer>
          <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:00:00" />
          </staticContent>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
                    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
                    <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>  
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    
    <location path="ngsw.json">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
            <staticContent>
                <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
            </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    
    <location path="ngsw-worker.js">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
            <staticContent>
                <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
            </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

App is NOT deployed under a subfolder.
If we don't delete any old files from site root, there is no error. Error appears only when we delete previous release files. When user open site, service workers should understand there is a new version to deploy and install it. So I don't understand why it seems to load old js files (that have been deleted before copying the new ones)

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I think this may have nothing to do with IIS caching, this issue may be related to Angular, I found a similar issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835

Comment: Yes, probably you are right, however on github some user suggested to write here because they say it's not angular related problem, but a IIS one.
The real problem is that when I open site now I'm getting that error. It seems to looking for old js files. I don't understand why. User's browser should have installed angular files in service workers, so how could it not find them?

Comment: I found a similar problem on SO and it has been resolved, you can created a new project, built a production version, redeploy to IIS. Update tsconfig.json:  "target": "es5".